# Make a code less repetitive

Tags: javascript, simplify

I wrote a part of code in a game which concern the moves of a character, and this code is very repetitive (almost all the same for the 4 directions).

I can't see how I can make it simpler, because of the tests in all 'if' conditions, because in the other case I would have make a system with a positive /negative variable that I could multiply to the position changes.

Thanks for your help !

```
for (var i = 0; i < boxArray.length; i++) {
    var box = boxArray[i];

    if (controller.left && currentLevel[this.id - this.moveHorizontal] != 1) {
        // Enregistrement de la position dans le tableau d'undo/redo
        this.index++;
        var array = [this.x, this.y, this.id];
        this.undoArray.push(array);
        // Si box à côté et pas de collision possible 
        if (box.id == this.id - this.moveHorizontal && currentLevel[this.id - this.moveHorizontal * 2] != 1 && currentLevel[this.id - this.moveHorizontal * 2] != 2) {
            // Décalage de la position du player 
            this.x -= this.boxWidth;
            this.id -= this.moveHorizontal;
            currentLevel[this.id] = 8;
            currentLevel[this.id + this.moveHorizontal] = 0;
            // Décalage de la position de la box
            box.x -= this.boxWidth; 
            box.id -= this.moveHorizontal;
            currentLevel[this.id - this.moveHorizontal] = 2;
            controller.left = false;
        }
        // Sinon si aucun objet à côté  
        else if (currentLevel[this.id - this.moveHorizontal] == 0 || currentLevel[this.id - this.moveHorizontal] == 3) {
            // Décalage de la position du player
            this.x -= this.boxWidth;
            this.id -= this.moveHorizontal;
            currentLevel[this.id] = 8;
            // Décalage de la position du sol
            currentLevel[this.id + this.moveHorizontal] = 0;
            controller.left = false;
        }
    }
    else if (controller.right && currentLevel[this.id + this.moveHorizontal] != 1) {
        this.index++;
        var array = [this.x, this.y, this.id];
        this.undoArray.push(array);
        if (box.id == this.id + this.moveHorizontal && currentLevel[this.id + this.moveHorizontal * 2] != 1 && currentLevel[this.id + this.moveHorizontal * 2] != 2) {
            this.x += this.boxWidth;
            this.id += this.moveHorizontal;
            currentLevel[this.id] = 8;
            currentLevel[this.id - this.moveHorizontal] = 0;
            box.x += this.boxWidth; 
            box.id += this.moveHorizontal;
            currentLevel[this.id + this.moveHorizontal] = 2;
            controller.right = false;
        }
        else if (currentLevel[this.id + this.moveHorizontal] == 0 || currentLevel[this.id + this.moveHorizontal] == 3) {
            this.x += this.boxWidth;
            this.id += this.moveHorizontal;
            currentLevel[this.id] = 8;
            currentLevel[this.id - this.moveHorizontal] = 0;
            controller.right = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you wrap parts of it in a function?

Comment: Maybe, but the problem is that I'm always gonna have the same weight of code, if I'm thinking good.

Comment: The purpose of separate functions is to minimize repetitive code; I'm just not sure about passing sematics in javascript. Is it pass-by-reference, or pass-by-value sematics in javascript. If there are pass-by-reference sematics, then you could decrease repetitive code.

Comment: Do you mean that I can make an other function havin a parameter 'direction' that define a specific value for each direction ?

Comment: No, wrap what you do per direction in a function.

Comment: Ah okay effectively it will be more ventilated and easy to read. Thank you !

Comment: Basically, you don't want to use conditionals to decide whether you're going to add or subtract. You can easily assign a variable whose value is either +amount_to_change or -amount_to_change and then use that variable in all your calculations.

Comment: @BaptisteMenard I think yo misunderstand, **wrap the COMMON routines in a function** and then call it with the parameters you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along these lines

```
for (var i = 0; i < boxArray.length; i++) {
    var box = boxArray[i];

    var direction = {
        'left': -1,
        'right': 1
    }; 

    for (var d in direction) {
        var mh = this.moveHorizontal * direction[d];

        if (controller[d] && currentLevel[this.id + mh])] {
            this.index++;
            var array = [this.x, this.y, this.id];
            this.undoArray.push(array);

            if (box.id == this.id + mh && currentLevel[this.id + mh * 2] != 1 && currentLevel[this.id + mh * 2] != 2) {
                this.x += this.boxWidth * direction[d];
                this.id += mh; 
                currentLevel[this.id] = 8;
                currentLevel[this.id + this.moveHorizontal] = 0;
                // Décalage de la position de la box
                box.x += this.boxWidth * direction[d]; 
                box.id += mh; 
                currentLevel[mh] = 2;
                controller[d] = false;
            } else if (currentLevel[this.id + mh] == 0 || currentLevel[this.id + mh] == 3) {
                // Décalage de la position du player
                this.x += this.boxWidth * direction[d];
                this.id += mh; 
                currentLevel[this.id] = 8;
                // Décalage de la position du sol
                currentLevel[this.id + (mh * -1)] = 0;
                controller[d] = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can definitely simplify this code.
For example, make an object like:

```
var moves = {
    moveLeft: function() { ... },
    moveRight: function() { ... }
};
```

Then you could say like

```
moves[side](...);
```

where side is a string indicating moveLeft or moveRight.

Besides that, you can group the repeated functionality, like this one that is repeated in both left and right:

```
function initMovement() {
   var array = [this.x, this.y, this.id];
   this.index++;
   this.undoArray.push(array);
}
```

Comment: The thing your missing is a lot of his conditionals are like `if (a + b == someValue) { \\ add a bunch of stuff } else if (a - b == someValue) { \\ subtract a bunch of stuff } which can be easily generalized.